# how to handle Set of not yet persisted entitys? Java JPA

Tags: java, jpa

i have two tables mapped by JPA with One to Many relationship. I want to add Set to the Blog entity, but since BlogNodes entry did not persisted yet, they havent Id field so i have nulpointer exception when i try to add second element to Collection. I've tried to use GenerationType.TABLE for id generator, but it doesn't help. Id is still null. Here are my entity classes with some fields ometted.

The Blog.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_blog")
public class Blog extends VersionedEntity{
(Identified id generation)
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Blog.class);
    //@ToDo: pass actual value to serialVersionUID
    //private static final long serialVersionUID = 1882566243377237583L;

...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentBlog", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval=true, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}) 
    private Set<BlogNode> blogNodes;
```

The BlogNode.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_blog_node")
public class BlogNode{
    /***************************************************************************************/
    @TableGenerator(name="tab", initialValue=0, allocationSize=5)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="tab")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Id
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof BlogNode)) return false;
        BlogNode that = (BlogNode) o;
        return that.id.equals(id);

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id == null ? 0 : id.hashCode();
    }
/*************************************************************************************/

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_blog_fk", referencedColumnName="id", nullable = true)
    private Blog parentBlog;
```

Main class

```
public List<Blog> createBlog(int n){
    params.put("BlogName","SampleBlogName");
    params.put("BlogAlias","defaultAlias");
    params.put("BlogDescription","defaultBlog description");
    List<Blog> newBlogs = new ArrayList<Blog>();
    while(n-->0){
        Blog entry = new Blog();
        entry.setBlogName(params.get("BlogName")+n);
        entry.setBlogAlias(params.get("BlogAlias")+n);
        entry.setBlogDescription(params.get("BlogDescription")+n);
        entry = blogDAO.save(entry);
        entry.setBlogNodes(createBlogNodes(entry, NUM_OF_NODES));
        entry = blogDAO.save(entry);
        newBlogs.add(entry);
    }

    return newBlogs;
}

private Set<BlogNode> createBlogNodes(Blog blog, int numOfNodes) {
    params.put("nodeTitle","SamplenodeName");
    params.put("nodeAlias","defaultAlias");
    params.put("nodeTeaser","default node teaser");
    params.put("nodeText","default node text");
    Set<BlogNode> nodes = new HashSet<BlogNode>();;
    while (numOfNodes-->0){ 
        BlogNode node = new BlogNode();
        node.setNodeTitle(params.get("nodeTitle")+numOfNodes);
        node.setNodeAlias(params.get("nodeAlias")+numOfNodes);
        node.setNodeText(params.get("nodeText")+numOfNodes);
        node.setParentBlog(blog);
        node.setNodeTeaser(params.get("nodeTeaser")+numOfNodes);
                    //Exception raises on the second iteration 
        nodes.add(node);
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

Can i beat this the other way, than persist single entitys of BlogNode separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the Node to a plain HashSet. The only way this causes an NPE is if it's coming from the `hashCode` or `equals` methods. Again, I'll point you to the [Hibernate manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-equalshashcode) on that subject. In short, those methods should not use the persistent ID for just this reason (among others).

Comment: Added method where i initialise Blog class and add blog nodes to Main class section

Comment: @Pilgrim, I updated the answer to reflect another potential problem I saw in the original code.

Comment: ok, thanks. will work on changing equals and hashcode methods